# How do I get a forex ticker working in yahoo finance?

Tags: python, finance, yahoo, yahoo-finance, stock

When I use any ticker that isn't a forex pair it works. But with the fx tickers it doesn't. I end up getting an error.

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_live_price
get_live_price('EURUSD=X')
```

Below Is the error I encountered.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-a1b6fb5ddbd7> in <module>
     4 
     5 #Stock = input('Stock:')
----> 6 get_live_price('EURUSD=X')
     7 #stockprice = get_live_price(str(Stock))
     8 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_live_price(ticker)
   336     '''    
   337 
--> 338     df = get_data(ticker, end_date = pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.DateOffset(10))
   339 
   340 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_data(ticker, start_date, end_date, index_as_date)
    58     html = html.decode()
    59 
---> 60     start = html.index('"HistoricalPriceStore"')
    61     end = html.index("firstTradeDate")
    62 

ValueError: substring not found
```

any ideas? It' clearly something to do with the ticker. When I use 'nflx' or 'aapl' it works like a charm. It's with forex that it seems to misbehave?

Answer (score 0):

That is the same error you get if the tag is made up trash.
Could you be trying to request a malformed tag/ticker?

```
In [12]: from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_live_price 
    ...: get_live_price('poop') 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-17c9a30a78a2> in <module>
      1 from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_live_price
----> 2 get_live_price('poop')
      3 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_live_price(ticker)
    336     '''    
    337 
--> 338     df = get_data(ticker, end_date = pd.Timestamp.today() + pd.DateOffset(10))
    339 
    340 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/yahoo_fin/stock_info.py in get_data(ticker, start_date, end_date, index_as_date)
     58     html = html.decode()
     59 
---> 60     start = html.index('"HistoricalPriceStore"')
     61     end = html.index("firstTradeDate")
     62 

ValueError: substring not found
```

Comment: Yes that's the issue. The ticker that yahoo have provided is garbage. I want to know what ticker actually works in order to get the current price of forex pairs

Comment: When I examine google page i see... <h1 class="D(ib) Fz(18px)" data-reactid="7">Alphabet Inc. (GOOG)</h1>  When I call GOOG i get a value, but when try with yours <h1 class="D(ib) Fz(18px)" data-reactid="7">EUR/USD (EURUSD=X)</h1> , EURUSD=X doesn't work

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34249/does-yahoo-google-no-longer-support-web-scraping-of-forex-data This is your issue, yahoo finance doesn't support this.